# Why exactly does akka need immutable messages

Tags: java, scala, thread-safety, akka, immutability

or put another way: are there proper uses of mutable messages?

The use case I am facing is that I want to process objects which basically are of type

```
Map<String,List<String>>
```

The typical processing an actor would do is to read or write some of the fields of the map. A condensed example is (leaving out `null`-tests etc.)

```
  map.get("somekey").add("new value");
```

My hunch is that keeping this immutable in Scala would be trivial by using the respective collection types. In Java it would require to go for some additional class library.

But: reading the Akka docs, I find that [sending a message introduces a happens-before relation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/1.3.1/general/jmm.html#Actors_and_the_Java_Memory_Model) between the last access of the sender and the first access of the receiving actor. So if the `map` is not immutable, nevertheless the sender should see all data.

Suppose I can make sure that the sender will never touch the `map` again once it is send, is there any other problem to expect with regards to threaded data access to this map?

Comment: You should avoid using weak abstractions like `Map<String, List<String>>. Create real abstractions for whatever that dictionary represents.

Comment: I think the first sentence should be "are there proper uses of **mutable** message?" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OP’s interpretation of the happens-before rule is correct: the “actor send rule” means that sending M to actor A happens-before processing M by A (this is what “the same” refers to).

To answer the main question: as long as only at most one actor can “own” the mutable map at any given point in time, this will work, and depending on the circumstances this may well be the most efficient solution to the problem. Guaranteeing the single-ownership will require a bit of discipline, though, which offsets the runtime advantage by a maintenance cost.

Although the original question leaves out the actual vehicle for transporting the `Map` I would like to reinforce Randall’s point that messages between actors should never be JDK types, since those lack semantic meaning. The `Map` should in this case be contained within a clearly named custom message type.

Comment: Thanks for stepping in, Roland!  Could you please also clarify when the 'actor send happens-before rule' would be invalid?  As in, "Both rules only apply for the same actor instance and are not valid if different actors are used." If I understand you correctly, you're saying that A1 sends M to A2, and the send in A1 happens-before processing of M by A2. Is that right?  And if so, what is meant by "different actors" in the docs?

Comment: What it means is that no other actors participate in these rules, happens-before is only established between the one or two that take part in the respective rule. When A sends to B then that says nothing about C, even if C happens to run "later" than the processing in B—unless a happens-before if established between B and C.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine if the data is effectively immutable.  This is easier to enforce if there data is immutable, however with discipline you can treat the map as effectively immutable after you send it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely true. While the receiving actor won't get corrupt data structures, they might not see all memory changes because a normal map never triggers a memory barrier so not all changes might have been flushed.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, this is a rule to avoid a ton of really weird problems.

The underlying problem is that the Java VM has some weird rules when one thread modifies memory and another thread reads that memory. Google for "Memory barriers" if you want to know the gory details.

So this means every language running on the VM is affected.

These rules in turn make it hard to tell when it would be safe to read a message that someone sent since the writing thread might not have yet flushed it's CPU's cache.

The solution is to force people to use the immutable patterns since then, the VM will make sure that the caches are in fact flushed when the Akka core takes the message and passes it to another thread.

Comment: My question wss specifically where or how the actors break, so this is not an answer.

Comment: If you use normal objects without synchronization, then changes in the sending actor might not be available to receiving actor when they run in different threads.

Comment: Immutable objects (for example by using final fields) are automatically synchronized properly before any other thread can see them, so they avoid all kinds of mysterious bugs.

Comment: In Akka, actors don't have to be tied to threads. I don't know the exact implementation but imagine the sender sends a message to itself. You would expect that Akka just calls `onReceive` during `tell`. But instead, the message gets queued. After a while, the actor gets attached to a new thread. So the same code of the same instance is executed by different threads. To make this work in all corner cases, Akka needs to synchronize somewhere. But I can't tell whether the docs say "Yes, Akka guarantees that this synchronization happens" or "without immutable objects, this will break".

Answer (score 0):

The [Akka docs you reference](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/general/jmm.html#actors-and-the-java-memory-model) state that the happens-before rules only apply to **the same** actor.  So if you send a message from one sender actor to a different receiver actor, the happens-before rules don't apply.

Also, as your code base evolves over time, it's going to be increasingly difficult to "make sure" that the only actor who every modifies that Map is the original sender.

Why not create a new immutable Map in the original sender, or any other place you modify the message contents before sending it to another actor?  Then you'll be 100% sure that no other actors can modify the message they've received, and you'll have easily avoided any concurrency problems.

Comment: If it is happens-before, it is happens-before, independent of between which classses the ralation is created. I stated already in the question that I know about the immutability and asked specifically where it would break without, so this is not an answer.

Comment: I think Aaron Digulla is on the right track here.  If the receiver your mutable message is a different actor than the one who sent it, there's no guarantee that local caches have been flushed and your changes are visible to the receiver.  I refer you again to the Akka docs, which clearly state about the 2 happens-before rules: "Both rules only apply for the same actor instance and are not valid if different actors are used."

Comment: What is the point of an actor sending messages to itself. The docs we both cite say: "The actor send rule: the send of the message to an actor happens before the receive of that message by the same actor." To me this a sounds like a slightly strange way of saying "the send of the message to actor B happens before the receive of that message by the actor B". In particular, if a message is send to B, no other actor than the addressed one benefits from the happens-before relation with regard to the message.

Comment: Caveat: I don't know much about Akka. But as I understand it, you have actors. Each actor is defined by a single Java type. But that doesn't mean that there is just a single actor of type `B`. The framework can be configured to have several actors of the same type for parallel processing of messages. That means that the sender can't (and shouldn't) know who will receive the message and whether that will be in the same thread.