# Akka passing pojo objects to onReceive method of my actor

Tags: java, akka

I am new to akka ,i tried only one actor processing an external api call till now. where in i created a an object UserData and made the object immutable and i kept sending to my actor (tell to my actor by passing UserData).
i have gone through the akka documentation (java 2.3.6)

Now i wanted to use akka for other use cases where i already have a an object which is a  POJO and i cannot make it immutable as other developers use it.I wanted to send this to an actor onRecieve method(tell to an actor)

But i am confused how the actor is assigned to thread and its fundamentals how it processes the mailbox of messages(my case pojos) and what happens if you send a POJO to an actor,assuming there is no static variables which change the state of POJO.?

Will there be any concurrency issues here?

Note:no one wants to change the pojo using setter methods once submitted to a actor but what happens if it gets changed

Am i on right track ? Because later i would like to use other features of the framework like routing by creating more actors.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564049/why-exactly-does-akka-need-immutable-messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think you should only pass immutable messages around. If this doesn't work with your *POJOs* you can always map them into immutable representations of themselves.

Comment: This is the best way to go if you can't change the original models.  Create an immutable copy and send that to the actor instead.