# Message immutability in Akka

Tags: java, akka

I'm just wondering if anything bad can happen in following scenario:

Let's assume I have 3 actors: A, B, C and one Message D that contains List. I'm sending this message through all of my actors (A -> B -> C -> A) and finally print out the result. Every actor reads List and adds extra String to it (making the Message mutable but there is only one possible owner of the message at particular point of time). Suppose also that I can make sure that the sender will never touch the List again once it is send. Is there any problem I may expect with regards to threaded data access to List?

Comment: And what guarantees that there's only "one owner of the message at particular point of time"? And why not simply use immutable collection?

Comment: It *should* work (unsure about internal tracking of messages), but why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

A version of what you are describing is absolutely possible even under the requirement of "immutability" of akka messages.

**Immutable Data Structures**

It is perfectly acceptable to change an immutable data structure, you just have to refer to the result with a different variable name.  As an example, given an immutable `List` of `String` objects you can always add one more String to the list:

```
val D = scala.collection.immutable.List("String0", "String1", "String2")

val updatedD = D :+ "String3"
```

Now, either `D` or `updatedD` are perfectly suitable akka messages.

**Akka Messaging**

Expanding on the immutable List example, we can add the functionality you described to two Actors:

```
class A(downstreamActor : ActorRef) extends Actor {
  override def receive : Receive = {
    case l : List[String] => downstreamActor ! (l :+ "ActorAValue")
  }
}//end class A

class B(downstreamActor : ActorRef) extends Actor {
  override def receive : Receive = {
    case l : List[String] => downstreamActor ! (l :+ "ActorBValue")
  }
}//end class B
```

We are mutating the "immutable" List several times, we just aren't using the same variable name for the updated value.  In fact, in the above example we aren't even assigning a name to the updated Lists it is just being passed along to the next downstream Actor.

**Message "Owner"**

There is no true "owner" of the message at any particular time, but that doesn't matter.  Each Actor/thread can have their own read-only copy of the data structure that matches the state of the world that they have received.

Comment: I posted my question because I've read in different topic that: "If you use normal objects without synchronization, then changes in the sending actor might not be available to receiving actor when they run in different threads." and "Immutable objects (for example by using final fields) are automatically synchronized properly before any other thread can see them, so they avoid all kinds of mysterious bugs." (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564049/why-exactly-does-akka-need-immutable-messages). As you know my objects (messages) aren't immutable...

Comment: @wenus1993 You should really strive for immutable message types.

Answer (score 0):

List is a immutable data structure , so appending data in List

```
val L = scala.collection.immutable.List("x1", "x2")
val newList = L :+ "X3"
```

:+   creates a new list which is expensive. 
So it would be better to use ListBuffer to add new elements. ListBuffer is mutable.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
var L= new ListBuffer[String]()
L += "x3"
```